# Consistent Database Export of Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, export, expdp

I'm quite confused and I need some clarification!

I do full export of database with Export Pump (for replication/duplication).

What I usually do is:

```
SQL>SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
SQL>STARTUP RESTRICT
```

Then export, so I can have a consistent export (DMP-file).

Now can I export only with the parameter `CONSISTENT=Y` and/or `FLASHBACK_SCN=SOME_NUMBER`?
What is the differences (if any), and when to use them?

I hope some one explain it to me in simple language!

What are the best practices in this regard?

Comment: There is no need to start Oracle in restricted mode in order to get a consistent dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Pump command-line arguments are partially backward-compatible with Export and Import utilities, and `CONSISTENT` maps to `FLASHBACK_TIME`.

`FLASHBACK_SCN` is used to specify system change number until all changes from the source database are exported. `FLASHBACK_TIME` allows you to specify change time. When you specify `CONSISTENT`, Data Pump Export determines the current time and uses that value for `FLASHBACK_TIME` implicitly.

For more info read Oracle Database Utilities.